# r XBRL package "404 Not Found" error with Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, xbrl

The following R code works fine from my Windows 8 laptop:

```
> inst<- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/51143/000104746916010329/ibm-20151231.xml"
> options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> xbrl.vars <- xbrlDoAll(inst, cache.dir = "XBRLcache", prefix.out = NULL, verbose=TRUE)
```

However, when I attempt to run it from my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, I receive the following output:

> Error in fileFromCache(file) :
>     Error in download.file(file, cached.file, method = "auto", quiet = !verbose) :
>     cannot download all files
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(file, cached.file, method = "auto", quiet = !verbose) :
>     URL 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/51143/000104746916010329/ibm-20151231.xsd': status was '404 Not Found'

It's finding the initial xml file but then cannot find the referenced schemas.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem, Windows 7 without any problem, Ubuntu 16.04 not possible!

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this? I currently hit the same issue with the latest R and XBRL.